# Android: DrawerLayout, выдвигающийся снизу

Tags: android, android-dialog, bottom-sheet

Понадобилось реализовать `DrawerLayout`, который будет выдвигаться снизу экрана. Причем, свайпом это сделать будет нельзя, только открыть и закрыть по действию. Выдвигаемая панель будет для ввода пароля. Так вот, может есть какая-нибудь библиотека? Читал про `BottomSheet`, но это не то, так как:

1) Панель делится на две части, нужна одна
2) Не должно быть управления свайпом
3) Не нашел как выдвигать/задвигать его программно.

Или же лучше сделать `AlertDialog` с анимацией видвигания снизу? Тогда как сделать, чтобы окошко было не в центре, а внизу?

Comment: Не знаю, откуда вы взяли ограничения `BottomSheet`, [в этой статье](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031) идет речь о том, что вам нужно, по видимому (выезжающий снизу произвольный Layot (или даже полноценный фрагмент) при нажатии на кнопку)

Comment: так же, как [отключить свайп](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35794264/disabling-user-dragging-on-bottomsheet) у `BottomSheet`

Comment: как быть с вечно торчящей первой панелью?

Comment: Если вы все же прочитаете статью, то увидите, что там ничего не "торчит", а в разделе 3 прямо сказано, когда и почему "торчит"

Comment: Еще можешь посмотреть в сторону SnackBar

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо за статью) Не заметил, когда гуглил ;) Сделайте ответом

Comment: На ответ мои комментарии не тянут, а писать ответ мне лень. Сделайте все, чтобы вместе работало и оформите, как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Убрал `peekHeight` и управляю виджетом из `BottomSheetBehavior` с помощью методов `getState()` и `setState()`